# Keeping a 2006 Giant SCR 3 on the road - 9 speed to 11 speed?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, repair

I have a Giant SCR 3 which was a freebie from a mate, who had it new.  It's approx a 2006 I think, and I've had it about 5 years.  I've spend a relatively small amount along the way at the LBS, keeping it going.

Due the serious mileage it's seen between the two of us, the following are now clear;

1. The original Tiagra 9x3 groupset is nearing End Of Life (confirmed by friendly LBS, who don't try to sell me anything I don't need)
2. The original Alex rims are WAY beyond the wear indicators, although, nothing bad has happened yet!
3. Braking is now a serious effort on the hands (needs new cables I guess)

As much out of nostalgia for my first decent road bike, I'm tempted to give it a new lease of life.  I have other bikes, but this is/was my go-to commuter, and old enough to lock up in town on a night out too.

I believe the 9 speed is now obsolete in Tiagra?  So do I go Sora 9 speed (Sora in 2019 perhaps similar standard to 2006 Tiagra?) 
OR, as I need to change wheels too, is this an opportunity to go to new 11 speed Tiagra?

Am I missing a trick here? Can I just by new cassette, chain-rings, chain, and keep it going...

Thanks all

James

PS: Little bike DIY experience to date, although I am mechanically minded.

Comment: Current Tiagra is 10 speed.

Answer (score 7):

I think your minimum refurb to bring the bike up to a good standard would be: new wheels; bottom bracket, chain, cassette and chain-rings; housings and cables (shift and brake); tires, brake pads, bar-tape; *and* a total, thorough cleaning and re-adjustment. This is assuming the derailleurs and shifters are actually working OK, and your LBS just means 'obsolete' when they say they are at 'end of life'.

That's a fairly big chunk of the bike, so you may want to go the whole way and upgrade the groupset. Personally I'd want at least 10 speed as an upgrade - Current Tiagra 4700 is 10 speed. Another option is looking for lightly used 105 5800 or Ultegra 6800 (or perhaps even R7000 or R8000) 11 speed components.

I'd look for a good set of lightly used wheels. As tech has moved to disc brakes and thru-axles you can probably find some really good light and strong rim/QR wheels for reasonable money.

Comment: In this context, I would expect that "end of life" means that the specific components fitted to the asker's bike are worn out and will soon need replacing. On the other hand, it might mean that it's becoming increasingly difficult to find parts, since Tiagra became 10-speed in 2011.

Comment: Minor point: if the OP doesn't have 11-spd compatible hubs, they can still use the current Ultegra's 11-34 cassette, as the largest cog has enough dish to clear the spokes on a 8/9/10spd freehub body.

Comment: And to your point about wheels, QR + rim brake compatible, Ultegra level tubeless ready wheels are available for ~$300 at various online retailers as of July 2019

Comment: @PaulH True, although the OP says they have worn out their rims, so new wheels are on the table.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus of course -- I just mentioned in the case that they find a good deal on non-11spd compat rims

Answer (score 1):

I may well be far too late but I upgraded my 2007 SCR 3.0 in Dec 2016.

I used a Tiagra 4700 bottom bracket, with a 2 x 10 Tiagra chainset - replaced the cranks, rear derailleur and cassette (11-34; we've got a lot of 20% hills around where I live). I replaced the shifter set and front derailleur with Tiagra 4700 as well. New Tiagra R451 brake calipers, etc. I replaced the wheels with a Mavic Aksium Elite clincher set but have since replaced those with a Shimano RS11 wheelset as I had worn the rims right down. I almost need to replace those now!

The whole lot cost me in the region of £600 but the frame is solid and suits me for sportives, long day rides or touring and I don't mind doing miles on bumpy canal paths or putting it on a plane in a C2C bag.

I haven't regretted doing it and I learnt a lot about bike maintenance and mechanics along the way.

Comment: OK but I'm not sure this really answers the question about parts compatibility for the asker's bike.

Answer (score 0):

I had an older LS Vortex with DA 9 sp and re-did the whole kit in R8000 (11 speed). New cable housings and rims as well. It was a sizeable investment but it was worth it. If you can find NOS in Ultegra 6800 you can't go wrong in my opinion. Used wheelset makes sense if you can inspect first.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I don't find this answer very helpful, as all you say is that it was expensive but you thought it was worth it. You haven't given any information that would help the asker tell if it will be worth it _to them_. Maybe they have different priorities to you; maybe they're not as wealthy as you and Ultegra would break the bank. What specifically about Ultegra do you think made it worth your money?